# Terraform RDS parameter group change pending reboot

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

**AWS RDS parameter group change.**

The script update the parameter group name from

```
"AB" to "DC".
```

But I noticed that it was waiting for "Pending Reboot". How can I get it auto rebooted upon ?

```
terraform apply "test-test-plan"
```

Comment: You need to set [`apply_immediately`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/db_instance.html#apply_immediately) to `true` to trigger a reboot. Remember that this is downtime inducing if you aren't using `multi_az` as well.

Comment: I added true already. It perfectly did apply_immediate. as a next step is "pending reboot". I am stuck there.

Comment: You have to do it when you make the change or any pending changes stay pending until the next reboot.

Comment: I have the same problem and even though `apply_immediately` was set to true, the RDS instance did not reboot following a `pending-reboot` parameter change. @ydaetskcoR Are you sure that parameter group changes trigger a reboot of an RDS instance?

Answer (score 2):

Some RDS parameter changes cannot be applied without a reboot.  The [terraform aws_db_parameter_group documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_parameter_group) states:

> apply_method - (Optional) "immediate" (default), or "pending-reboot". Some engines can't apply some parameters without a reboot, and you will need to specify "pending-reboot" here.

So this may also be true with parameter group changes.

Answer (score 0):

According to AWS documentation:

> Most modifications to a DB instance you can either apply immediately
> or defer until the next maintenance window. Some modifications, such
> as parameter group changes, require that you manually reboot your DB
> instance for the change to take effect.

So I don't think that *terraform* is able to do it since it uses the AWS API, either you can wait for the next maintenance window or try to reboot your RDS manually on the console.